# get element located by img using any of its attributes which ever is possible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

i am using selenium java , and i want to click on one of the images and also i am not supposed to use xpath as it changes all the time , i am sharing my console error message and html code as well

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'AWAIS-PC', ip: '192.168.1.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [c2f759fa459cab68170d6765738976b5, findElement {using=css selector, value=img[@alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\WRP\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55963}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:55963/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: c2f759fa459cab68170d6765738976b5
```

my script is

```
 waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img[@alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")));
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[@alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use XPath:

```
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//img[@alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")).click();
```

Comment: thanx alot  , but is there any way i can locate this element using css selector method , would be really appreciated

Comment: Checkout my updated answer. I didn't test it

Comment: not working i am getting this error 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: img[alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  '] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: It was just a guess. I'll remove it from my answer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'AWAIS-PC', ip: '192.168.1.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1'

Command: [005a8524a5d23857ea2dc684ceb320ec, findElement {using=id, value=wzrk-cancel}]
why do i get cannot determine loading status error message what is the meaning of it

Comment: Is this related to your initial question? If not please create a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have provided `@` with attribute name, when you are using `css selector` `@` is **not** required with attribute name.That's the reason you are getting following error `An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

You should use below two options:
one with exact match and the other starts-with using css selector.

Option 1:

```
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img[alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton  ']")).click();
```

Option 2 : Starts-with

```
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img[alt^='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton']")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt^='hover state of Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton']")).click();
```